# How to pass user information from server to webpage for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am building a chrome extension that would insert a login button on a webpage. When users click on the button, they will be directed to a login page and then redirected back. I would like to pass information during redirection.

Here is the sequence:

1. say cnn.com (on login button click)
2. [my Backend] /authenticate is called
3. (supported service) login page is displayed
4. [my Backend] /callback is called
5. redirect to cnn.com on success

I don't know how to pass the "user" info to the page or the extension on redirect, during this step `[my Backend] /callback > redirect to xyz.com`

I am inserting the button using content script. I am trying to find ways to send user info to the extension during redirection and store it for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the state of the user, and whether or not they should be logged in on a cookie on your own domain.

Chrome extensions allow you to access cookies on any domain you'd like, as long as you specify the correct permissions on your manifest.

Then, you can use the [chrome.cookies API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) in order to access cookies on your own domain, even if your Chrome extension is running on a different web page.  Remember to use `chrome.cookies.get() / getAll()` instead of `document.cookie` to properly access cookie data across domains.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use an existing authentication scheme, such as [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0)?

Comment: I am not familiar with SAML. Will look it up. I am using passport for authentication.